# Provide auto guidance comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments

I'm proposing that some (a small selection) of boilerplate comments be provided for easy use when responding to unanswerable questions. A close vote for duplication does this, kind of.

It occurred to me after close-voting a question recently that was too broad.  This question was asked by a very new user to Stack Overflow. It would be nice if I could simply click a link that would add a comment to the 'How to Ask' guidance.

Maybe this could be provided to help users that are relatively new to Stack Overflow (by date)?

Comment: There's a [userscript](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) for that.

Comment: How could I never encounter userscript before? ;)

Comment: Still might be nice to make it first class, and context specific.

Comment: Note that they do get a link to how to ask when the on-hold banner arrives.

Comment: @jonrsharpe true, but by then a new user may feel a bit rejected and frustrated.  Somehow, the term 'on-hold' doesn't imply 'please improve your question a bit'.

Comment: @DavinTryon *"If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question."*

Comment: Are you aware that you can type `[ask]` to include [ask] in your comment? (Other [magic links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/298072) are available..)

Comment: @Sayse thanks, yes.  However usually that requires a few clicks and some typing.  It just seems like an action that must occur many, many times and many of the responses are generic.

Comment: Do know that the SOCVR chatroom maintain a collection of autocomments [here](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments) that can be used with the userscript pointed out by @oded. Feel free to add stuff you feel is missing